# What is a Wizard's Wireless?

Tags: harry-potter

From the GoF, right before the Yule Ball, there's a mention of the Weird Sisters wizarding band, and there's a mention about a device(?) called a wizard's wireless.

What is this device, as a "wireless" usually refers to a cell phone, which are considered Muggle artifacts by the wizarding community?

> ...Exactly who or hat the Weird Ssters were Harry didn't know, **never having access to a wizard's wireless**, although...

Comment: No, a wireless is not a cell phone. It's a radio. A wizard’s wireless is simply the wizarding equivalent of a radio, like the one Mrs Weasley uses to listen to Celestina Warbeck on. (I don't remember the mentioning in question offhand. Could you add in the actual quote?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless#Radio

Comment: Please see: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wireless.  The first 3 in "noun" are regarding wireless phones, also known as cell phones.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that if a Brit talks about ‘a wireless’, they’re almost certainly talking about a radio. I’ve never heard anyone, from any country, call a mobile phone ‘a wireless’. Mobile phones make use of wireless telephony, yes, but I’ve never heard of anyone calling them ‘wirelesses’. (Only the third is actually clearly about mobile phones; the first two are about the technology and its products in general. If you compare with [Merriam-Webster’s definitions for AmE](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wireless), they don’t even mention that meaning.)

Comment: I have a "wireless" phone.  It's connected to my land-line.  It has a base that is connected to the phone line.  I can go wherever I want in the house (and to some extent outside the house) with the handset.  Thus, it is my "wireless" phone.  But I would never call my cell phone "wireless".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A "[wireless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless#Radio)" is a (largely English) idiom for a radio receiver. The opposite of a *wired* receiver such as a telegraph.

> They were all supposed to be listening to a Christmas broadcast by Mrs
> Weasley’s favourite singer, Celestina Warbeck, whose voice was
> warbling out of the large wooden wireless. Fleur, who seemed to find
> Celestina very dull, was talking so loudly in the corner that a
> scowling Mrs Weasley kept pointing her wand at the volume control, so
> that Celestina grew louder and louder.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sup>

In the later books we learn that there's also a [password/encryption component](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley%27s_wireless_radio) to the device, allowing pirate transmissions to be received by those capable of guessing the correct passcode

> Ron spent evening after evening using his wand to beat out various
> rhythms on top of the wireless while the dials whirled. Occasionally
> they would catch snatches of advice on how to treat dragon pox, and
> once, a few bars of ‘A Cauldron Full of Hot, Strong Love’. While he
> tapped, Ron continued to try to hit on the correct password, muttering
> strings of random words under his breath. ‘They’re normally something
> to do with the Order,’ he told them. ‘Bill had a real knack for
> guessing them. I’m bound to get one in the end …’
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sup>

Comment: +1 for largely English, no wonder it didn't make complete sense to me. I do however have a follow-up question as to how they work though.....

Comment: They work by magic, of course.  ;-)